# C++ program compiles and runs in codeblocks, but can't compile it in terminal

Tags: c++, c++11, terminal, codeblocks

I created a C++ project that contains several source files and header files. The program compiles and runs well in codeblocks, but I can't compile it in terminal.

All the files are in the same folder.

Here are the command I enter:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp file1.cpp file1.h
```

It shows:

```
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
```

And a punch of errors about:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
```

In the head file.

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, when you include a header somewhere, it has access to what is included by the source file that included it. When you try to compile it though, it behaves as a source code and will expect to have those things explicitly included.

Comment: Long-story-short: Don't try to compile headers, as has already been answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should to avoid to compile an *header* file (`.h`).

Try with:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp file1.cpp
```

The header file is something that the *preprocessor* will include in the *cpp* files which need it (those *compilation units* which use `#include` pre-processor directive).

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't compile header files, only source files. In the source files that need to reference the header file, put `#include "file1.h"` at the top.